# How can i change my default sound card via alsamixer or anything that works

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, soundcard, pipewire

I'm trying to change the default sound card setting because my mic used to work smoothly, but now my voice is terrible. So I decided to change the default sound card because the default one is the wrong sound card. I'm not a Linux expert, but I'm watching YouTube videos to change things, and I got pipewire. How can I change the default sound card?